# Enable scroll in specified div?

Tags: html, css

I have following situation. Container `c` has fixed property. It's always 100% height. Not moving.

Container `b` has dynamic height.

Container `a` (body) can't have scrollbar visible at all.

**Question**: How to force the scrollbar from `body` to disappear, but the scrollbar in container `b` to appear? Thanks!

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.b,
.c {
  width: 50%;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.c {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
  </div>
  <div class='c'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to SirExotic

Your .b container needs content that exceeds the height of b to activate the scroll bar.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden; /* added */
}

.a {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.b,
.c {
  width: 50%;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.b-content {
   min-height: 800px;
 }

.c {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <div class="b-content">
      here I am
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='c'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Credit is all you man :) I thought that because `.b` had a fixed height, that was enough to enable scrolling.

Comment: Well that's okay, I just set the height for this example. If your context exceeds the height of the container, the scroll will activate is the point I'm trying to get across there. For instance, hit reply on this comment and then type out a ton of letters. The scrollbar activates when the size of the text exceeds the size of the container. Just try it out!